# FlySystem problem, file can not be uploaded into directly that exists

Tags: 8, files

I had created a question in order to config **FlySystem module** correctly for Drupal 8 to work with ftp.
you can see it [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298924/flysystem-error-message-driver-is-missing).

fortunately with *@mbomb007 helps*, I could do it.

but another problem happened and I don't know that is the reason.
problem is when flysystem module tries to upload a file into directory that exists, upload fails and in status message I see this error

> The upload directory 2020-12 for the file field field_image could not
> be created or is not accessible. A newly uploaded file could not be
> saved in this directory as a consequence, and the upload was canceled

Imagine when module wants to upload a file into 2020-12 directory. if directory doesn't exist, it creates directory 2020-12 at first and then upload file into it. there is no problem till now.

but for the second upload, if module wants to crated another file into same directory 2020-12, upload fails.
I searched a lot into files and module issues page. I think problem is related to result of is_writable() function. this function returns FALSE for created directory that we want to upload file into it.
I checked FTP configuration on remote server. tried to set permission to 777 for all folders. but problem not solved.

I am searching more but I am not sure what exactly causes this error.

Comment: In your other question you mentioned S3 in a comment. Check your S3 bucket permissions, [follow this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=173&v=nL01TBjJDAQ&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: thanks a lot. I will watch it. but I think there are a lot of differences between S3 and FTP

Comment: I test this module on my machine. I run local ftp server on my computer. created local ftp account with all permissions. unfortunately I saw problem is still there. so it doesn't matter whether server is CPANEL shared hosting or FTP on local host. this module has problem when tries to upload files into directory that exists.

Comment: `set permission to 777` Permissions aren't enough, make sure your files folder has assigned the correct **[owner/group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljSYS.png)**, that belongs to the server.

Comment: Dear @NoSssweat, I tested it. it didn't work.